# React admin login using customRoute not rerendering resources/drawer

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, admin-on-rest

I am using react-admin for a dashboard. Everything works fine, but using login on a custom page (using customRoutes) is not rererendering the drawer after the redirect.

Those are my custom routes:

```js
export default [
    <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} noLayout />,
];
```

Part of the `SignUp` component (the values contain phone and password, where phone is the username):

```js
    const login = useLogin();
    const notify = useNotify();
    const classes = useStyles();
    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            phone: '',
            password: '',
            role: '',
            first_name: '',
            last_name: ''
        },
        onSubmit: async (values, { setStatus }) => {
            try {
                const response = await httpClient('/api/auth/users/', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify(values),
                })
                login({ phone: values.phone, password: values.password })
                    .catch(() => notify('Invalid phone number or password'));
            } catch (e) {
                notify(e.message, 'error');
            }
        }
    });
```

my `Admin` component:

```js
  <Admin layout={Layout} dataProvider={drfProvider('/api', httpClient)} authProvider={authProvider} loginPage={LoginPage} customRoutes={customRoutes}>
    {role => {
      return [
        <Resource name="checkins" list={CheckInList} create={CheckInCreate} show={CheckInShow} icon={PersonPinCircleIcon} options={{ label: 'Check Ins' }} />,
        <Resource name="myplaces" list={role === ROLES.HOST ? PlaceList : null} edit={PlaceEdit} create={PlaceCreate} show={PlaceShow} icon={StoreIcon} options={{ label: 'My Places' }} />,
        <Resource name="myrooms" list={role === ROLES.HOST ? RoomList : null} edit={RoomEdit} create={RoomCreate} show={RoomShow} icon={RoomIcon} options={{ label: 'My Rooms' }} />,
        <Resource name="guests" list={role === ROLES.HOST ? GuestList : null} create={GuestCreate} show={GuestShow} icon={PeopleIcon} />,
        <Resource name="places" />,
        <Resource name="rooms" />,
      ]
    }}
  </Admin>
```

As you can see depending on the role, some routes won't be rendered. The problem is, the Admin component is only rendered in the background when I go to /signup page, and after the login redirect, it's not rerendered, so I don't see the correct resources.

Here is also my authProvider:

```js
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';

export default {
    // called when the user attempts to log in
    login: ({ phone, password }) =>  {
        console.log('login start')
        const request = new Request('/api/auth/jwt/create/', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ phone, password }),
            headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
        });
        return fetch(request)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) {
                    throw new Error(response.statusText);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(({ access }) => {
                localStorage.setItem('token', access);
            });
    },
    // called when the user clicks on the logout button
    logout: () => {
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        return Promise.resolve();
    },
    // called when the API returns an error
    checkError: ({ status }) => {
        if (status === 401 || status === 403) {
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
            return Promise.reject();
        }
        return Promise.resolve();
    },
    // called when the user navigates to a new location, to check for authentication
    checkAuth: () => {
        return localStorage.getItem('token')
            ? Promise.resolve()
            : Promise.reject();
    },
    // called when the user navigates to a new location, to check for permissions / roles
    getPermissions: () => {
        console.log('getPermissions start')
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        let role = null;
        try {
            const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
            role = decodedToken.role;
        } catch (e) {
            role = '';
        }
        console.log('role ' + role)
        return Promise.resolve(role);
    }
};
```

A custom login page, however works correctly, so probably because we don't need a customRoute for it. I think it's about how react-admin manages the customRoutes.